# Win32: Toolbar dialog seems to never get focus and causes the main window to process slow?

Tags: c, dialog, winapi, modeless

I'm writing an application following [this tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/). I'm aware that this tutorial dates, and as such, I have adapted the code to take into consideration the unicode.

I have a main window which looks like an MDI. Then, I have a **View** menu which toggles a Toolbar dialog as to be shown and hidden.

When I show the dialog, it is displayed, but the `PUSHBUTTON`s are not displayed correctly. They only appear when I click my main window again.

Plus, I don't seem to be able to click neither of the `PUSHBUTTON`s into my toolbar dialog.

The resources (`resource.h`) are defined as follows (only showing what is relevant to this question):

```
#define IDD_TOOLBAR              102
#define IDC_PRESS               1000
#define IDC_OTHER               1001
#define ID_VIEW_SHOWTOOLBAR    40002
#define ID_VIEW_HIDETOOLBAR    40003
```

And the dialog as follows in my `.rc` file:

```
IDD_TOOLBAR DIALOGEX 0, 0, 85, 50
    STYLE    DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_MODALFRAME | WS_CAPTION | WS_POPUP
    EXSTYLE  WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW
    CAPTION  L"Toolbar"
    FONT     8, "MS Shell Dlg"
BEGIN
    PUSHBUTTON     L"&Press this button",     IDC_PRESS, 7,  7, 70, 14
    PUSHBUTTON     L"&Or this one",           IDC_OTHER, 7, 28, 70, 14
END
```

And showing it as follows in my **WndProc** function:

```
// As a global variable I have my toolbar handler.
HWND g_hToolbar = NULL;

BOOL CALLBACK ToolbarDlgProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (Msg) {
        case IDC_OTHER:
            MessageBoxW(hWnd, L"You just clicked IDC_OTHER!", L"Information", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            break;
        case IDC_PRESS:
            MessageBoxW(hWnd, L"You just clicked ODC_PRESS!", L"Information", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            break;
        default:
            return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (Msg) {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
                case ID_VIEW_HIDETOOLBAR:
                    ShowWindow(g_hToolbar, SW_HIDE);
                    break;
                case ID_VIEW_SHOWTOOLBAR: 
                    if (NULL == g_hToolbar) 
                        g_hToolbar = CreateDialogW(GetModuleHandle(NULL)
                                                    , MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_TOOLBAR)
                                                    , hWnd
                                                    , ToolbarDlgProc);

                    ShowWindow(g_hToolbar, SW_SHOW);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

And here's the way I handle the different messages for my main window and my dialog in my message loop in my **WinMain** function.

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) {
    // Declaring, registring and creating my main window to hWnd here...
    MSG Msg;

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nShowCmd);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    while (GetMessageW(&Msg, hWnd, 0, 0) > 0) {
        if (!IsDialogMessageW(g_hToolbar, &Msg)) {
            TranslateMessage(&Msg);
            DispatchMessageW(&Msg);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is:

1. **I don't seem to be able to click on my dialog's buttons.**
2. **When I attempt to click on my dialog's buttons, my main window becomes very slow to respond to its own messages.**

That is, when I want to show my Toolbar dialog as a modeless dialog, because when I show it modal, it works perfectly!

Any clue to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code looks pretty ok. From your description it looks like the problem is in message pump, but it looks ok. Do you have any special code in ToolbarDlgProc we need to look at?

Comment: Edited the `ToolbarDlgProc` to reflect what's in it. Thanks for taking the time to look at my problem. =) I also doubt the message pump, but since I am still learning Win32's, I can't get to debug correctly.

Comment: Just tried MDI and SDI application with your code, it works OK for me. Hve no idea... I know it will not help with your problem, but if you want to use Win32Api, I would recommend you to look at WTL, it's good wrapper for WinApi, good stuff :)

Comment: Thanks DReJ for this suggestion about WTL. I shall take an eye out to it when my knowledge about Win32 API grows better. As for now, I'm interested to better understand Win32 API, to know what's under the hood of .NET, since when I began to program, the Win32's were too advanced for me to understand correctly. As of now, they seems easy enough to learn them fast and get to the next level afterwards. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, as DReJ said in the above comment, in my message pump.

The trouble is that I write:

```
while (GetMessageW(&Msg, hWnd, 0, 0) > 0) {
    // Processing message here...
}
```

And that I shall write:

```
while (GetMessageW(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
    // Processing message here...
}
```

So, because I was getting the messages for a given window, the **hWnd** instance, my ToolbarDialog seemed to lack of time to draw itself completely or something like it. Replacing **hWnd** for **NULL** in that scenario solved the problem entirely.