# Win32: What is making my message loop work incorrectly in that example?

Tags: c, message, winapi, windows-messages, message-loop

I recently ran into a situation where I wanted to use a modeless dialog in Win32's.

***[Win32: Toolbar dialog seems to never get focus and causes the main window to process slow!?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464740/win32-toolbar-dialog-seems-to-never-get-focus-and-causes-the-main-window-to-proc)***

And I figured out that this was my message loop:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) {
    // Doing required stuff here...

    while (GetMessage(&Msg, hWnd, 0, 0) > 0) {
        // Processing messages here...
    }
}
```

In fact, this message loop works fine as long as I don't have any modeless dialog, as it works perfectly fine with modal dialogs, since they process their own message loop. My modeless dialog worked flawlessly when I replaced the `hWnd` instance for `NULL`. I just don't get the difference, except that it seems that I get the messages not for one particularly window.

**Can someone explain what is making this message loop work inccorectly?**

As this one:

```
while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
    // Processing messages here...
}
```

works flawlessly!

Comment: Yeah, a bit too obvious.  A modeless dialog also requires IsDialogMessage() in the message loop.

Comment: @Hans: Yes, indeed. I shall have had written it in these sample, I did include it as shown in my question in link, though I didn't illustrate it here. My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the difference is pretty obvious: you specified a `HWND` in `GetMessage`. So, you are not processing any messages for any other windows, your toolbar included. See the docs for [GetMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644936%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to make sure I understood my error correctly, and your answer reflects what I thought, though I was not sure about it. =)